# Adding an element to a struct that contains a char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

Okay so I am sure this is not too difficult a question but I am lost after trying to figure it out for so long so here is the code first the declaration for my structs.

```
struct GraphicElement {
    char* fileName;
    struct GraphicElement* pNext;
  };
    struct RasterGraphic {
    struct GraphicElement* GraphicElements;
  };
```

Then I call a function that takes care of the initialization which I believe is working properly.

```
int main(void)
{
char response;
BOOL RUNNING = TRUE;
struct RasterGraphic RG;
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
InitRasterGraphic(&RG);
```

The init function is as follows

```
void InitRasterGraphic(struct RasterGraphic* pA)
{

pA->GraphicElements = malloc(sizeof(struct GraphicElement));

if (pA->GraphicElements == NULL) return;
//pA->GraphicElements = 0;
//pA->GraphicElements->pNext = NULL;
//pA->GraphicElements->fileName = NULL;
pA->GraphicElements->fileName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

return;
}
```

So the next part of code is where I am going to ask my question. I have a function that takes a user input of some sort of string. Id like to take that input and add it to the next element. So every time the user calls the function they put in their input and its added to the next element. My code right now is a mess and I know it definitely is probably way off I've tried a bunch of things already. I believe I need to use realloc. What I am not able to wrap my head around here is how to take the input and add it so that later on I can printf all the elements in order. so for example user calls function 3 times and puts in inputs "hello" "world". Later I would like to cycle through and print 
graphic 1 is "hello"
graphic 2 is "world"

```
void InsertGraphicElement(struct RasterGraphic* pA)
{
char response[256];
printf("Insert a GraphicElement in the RasterGraphic\nPlease enter the GraphicElement filename: ");
scanf("%s", &response[0]);
pA->GraphicElements->fileName = realloc(pA->GraphicElements, 256*sizeof(char));
pA->GraphicElements++;
strcpy(pA->GraphicElements->fileName, &response);
if (pA->GraphicElements == 1){

    printf("\nThis is the first GraphicElement in the list\n");
    }

return;
}
```

Comment: The expression `pA->GraphicElements == 1` should never be true. If you need to know the size of the list, you need to keep track of it yourself, like a member in the `RasterGraphic` structure.

Comment: You have `response`, so why not `pA->GraphicElements->fileName = realloc(pA->GraphicElements, strlen (response) + 1);` ?  Saves a lot of wastes space. That should be `strcpy(pA->GraphicElements->fileName, response);` (not `&response`), `response` is converted to a pointer on access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the few issues in your code.

1. I believe `InitRasterGraphic` should just initialize the `pA->GraphicElements = NULL` instead of `malloc`ing it. Since same should be handled in `InsertGraphicElement` function.
2. `pA->GraphicElements->fileName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` this will just allocate the `memory` of size single `char` and there is no point in `alloc`ing and `realloc`ing.
3. `scanf("%s", &response[0]);` should be `scanf("%s", &response[0]);`.
4. `pA->GraphicElements++;` This is wrong instead use one more member to maintain the number of nodes in the list.

Hence after correcting the above issues your code will look like below.

your `RasterGraphic` will look like below.

```
struct RasterGraphic {
    int numNodes;
    struct GraphicElement* GraphicElements;
  };
```

Your `InitRasterGraphic` will look like below.

```
void InitRasterGraphic(struct RasterGraphic* pA)
{

    pA->GraphicElements = NULL;
    pA->numNodes = 0;

   return;
}
```

Your `InsertGraphicElement` will look like below.

```
void InsertGraphicElement(struct RasterGraphic* pA)
{
   struct GraphicElement *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
   if (newNode == NULL) return;

   newNode->fileName = malloc(256*sizeof(char));
   if (newNode->fileName == NULL) return;
   newNode->pNext = NULL;


   printf("Insert a GraphicElement in the RasterGraphic\nPlease enter the GraphicElement filename: ");
   scanf("%s", newNode->fileName);


   if (pA->GraphicElements == NULL)
   {
      pA->GraphicElements = newNode;
   }
   else
   {
      struct GraphicElement *tempHead = pA->GraphicElements;
      while(tempHead->pNext != NULL)
      {
         tempHead = tempHead->pNext;
      }
      tempHead->pNext = newNode;
   }

   pA->numNodes++;
   if (pA->numNodes == 1){
      printf("\nThis is the first GraphicElement in the list\n");
   }

  return;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` will always be == 1, if the language calls itself C